# Notification for Object modification?

Tags: c++

I am having a very simple class like this

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){}
    ~MyClass(){}

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

In my application I am just creating an object of this class. And I am trying to use class object in my method. Now I want to have some kind of notification mechanism placed so that if by mistake some one tries to modify this object my application gets notified and I could make decision on that.

Is there any way to implement this mechanism.

I have a contraint that all my datamembers should be public.

Comment: That's up to the class. If it shouldn't be modified, don't expose anything that can modify it.

Comment: @chris I using boost multiindex in my application and for that I have to make all data members public.

Comment: What the rationale for the "constraint that all my datamembers should be public"? Assuming there's a good reason, btw, why not use `struct` instead?

Comment: @0xbe5077ed I have already commented about my constraint

Comment: Using boost multiindex in your application does not necessitate making all your datamembers public.

Comment: well the encapsulation would usually work if you put your `struct` into some wrapper class that implements getter functions (like `getA(){return obj.a;}` and only exposes the real `MyClass` object to `friend`s or via an interface like `getMyClassInstance() {return obj;}`

Comment: even more general conecept is the ["observer pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: also interesting read: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html

Comment: @Pavel I want some thing like If the state of an object changes a notification is sent implicitly and I could do something after getting this notification.

Comment: I understood. Buy don't expect any magic, memory is just a storage so if someone modifies a byte, nobody will know without putting additional logic into *how* the members are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that variables have not been changed, you will need to put in a checksum.  Any time there is a controlled write to the variables, the checksum needs to be recalculated.

Periodically, calculate the checksum of the member variables and compare to the stored checksum.

The checksum could be an additive, xor, CRC, md5 or SHA-1 to name a few.

Another option is to maintain a shadow or mirror copy.  The controlled write function would copy the values to the shadow after the write operation.

My recommendation is to change the access privilege of the members and see what blows up.  Those are the function that should be modified to use a "properties" function.